# MYSQL GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP make touples with most NULL values appear first

Tags: mysql

I need the output of the following code

```
SELECT Model, Make, Country, owner, condition, COUNT(*)
FROM test
GROUP BY Model, Make, Country, owner, condition WITH ROLLUP;
```

to be ordered by the number of NULL values in each touple. Meaning a touple that have 5 NULL will appear first, then the one with 4 NULL and so on.

I tried to do GROUP BY ASC, but it does not work. Any ideas how can this be done easily ?

Comment: "ROLLUP has a more complex effect when there are multiple GROUP BY columns. In this case, each time there is a “break” (change in value) in any but the last grouping column, the query produces an extra super-aggregate summary row. " And you want this row to appear before values, not after?

Comment: Basically yes. For example since it will output the total number at the end, I want that number to appear first, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP` is not compatible with sorting. But you can put it into subquery and sort like this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM
  (
    SELECT Model, Make, Country, owner, condition, COUNT(*) AS items_count
    FROM test
    GROUP BY Model, Make, Country, owner, condition WITH ROLLUP
  ) AS t
ORDER BY Model, Make, Country, owner, condition
```

MySQL sort algorithm will put nulls first, because NULL is always less than some value.